# Python error log location

Tags: python, apache, flask, logging, python-logging

I am developing a python application on `flask` framework. And I use `.wsgi` to deploy it. I got confused by error log locations. It looks like Python errors and debug information are put into different log files.

First of all, I specify both access and error log locations in the `apache` `vhost` file.

```
<VirtualHost *:myport>
    ...
    CustomLog /homedir/access.log common
    ErrorLog /homedir/error.log
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I also know there is another `apache` error log, `/var/log/httpd/error_log`. My access logs were printed into the right place, `/homedir/access.log`.

But, error log looks weird. The Python errors, like `SyntaxError`, uncaught exceptions went to the log file specified in `vhost` file (`/homedir/error.log`). But, any log messages generated by python `logging` module, went to the "default" error log (`/var/log/httpd/error_log`).

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix it? I want these two logs go to the same place.

---

Thanks for the comments. Here is the code I set up logger

```
import logging

# I didn't specify the stream, so it suppose to be stderr
# Don't know why stderr points to apache /var/log/*, rather than my error log

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s : %(pathname)s:%(lineno)s - %(msg)s")
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger = logging.getLogger('foo')
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Then, I logged messages in this way.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('foo.bar')

logger.debug('Some debug information')
```

But, the log goes to /var/log/httpd/error_log, rather than the log specified in apache vhost file.

Comment: Maybe it does fix your problem, but you got a typo in your vhost file (or in the given code snippet only): `VirutalHost` is not the same as `VirtualHost`

Comment: @Michael sorry about that. just corrected it.

Comment: How are you initializing the logging module and levels in your flask application, and how are you invoking the logging methods?

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/errorhandling/

Comment: @bwbrowning I just edited the question, including more information. Thanks.

Comment: How about setting the log level inside your virtualhost directive to info?

Comment: have you fixed the problem? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You should use `flask.logging.default_handler` instead of `logging.StreamHandler()`, as the former use `request.environ['wsgi.errors']`to create stream but latter didn't, refer [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/logging.py#L22) for detail.

And for more information about `request.environ['wsgi.errors']`, see [here](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/debugging-techniques.html#apache-error-log-files).